# Remote Desktop Protocol - can't connect from Internet Windows 10 Pro

Tags: rdp, local-area-network, windows-10

I have a problem connecting to Windows 10 Pro with RDP
I have new computer with Windows 10 Pro installed. Updated fully with Windows Update.
I configured RDP access to this computer. It works fine from LAN but I cant connect from Internet. I'm sure that it is this computer problem.
I have another server Windows Server 2012 in the same network and I can connect without problem.
More details:
WS2012 has address 192.168.1.1
Win10 computer has address 192.168.1.2
Ports redirection configured 
TCP/UDP 3389 to 3389 on 192.168.1.1
TCP/UDP 12345 to 3389 on 192.168.1.2 (if I switch redirection to 192.168.1.1 I can connect on port 12345 so redirecting works fine)

I can connect from my own laptop to WS2012 through Internet
I can't connect to Win10
Port testing shows that it is closed from outside.

In local network both servers can connect without problem and my own laptop can connect to both servers too (from LAN).
I changed IPs, changed ports redirecting, disabled firewall, checked policies, disabled antivir, uninstalled almost all software.

I can connect to windows server and cant connect to win 10 with the same configs and tools.
I have no idea what can I try more.
Tried everything.
Any clue to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

Today I figured it out. I post an answer in case someone has similar problem.
The reason that it didn't work was my network configuration. I have 2 network gateway. First for RDP only (public IP address and dynamic dns configured), second is router with load balancer as default gateway.
The default gateway for DHCP server was the load balancer. So when RDP was correctly incoming from RDP router, the response pockets were send to default gateway instead RDP router and were droped.
That's all.
Static configuration with correct gateway fixed the problem.

regards and thanks @George for help. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely NOT the Windows 10 system.  If it were, RDP would not work on the LAN side either.

Since it works from a LAN but not remotely, there's two possibilities - 1) ingress forwarding is busted, and/or 2) egress forwarding is busted.

One, the router/gateway is not forwarding requests to it properly.

Two, the system is unable to respond back out the router to world+dog, so any connection attempts time out waiting for a client response.

Since you also have a Windows 2012 Server running, using the default port (3389) for RDP, it would seem that your redirected port 12345 is not being passed across the router properly.  Try disabling RDP on the 2012 system, setting your Windows 10 desktop to use the default port, and swapping the IP's so that the router directs RDP traffic to the system you're testing.

Once you're sure it works using the default port, then try setting up the redirected port to the same IP.  The process is simply a matter of changing one thing at a time, then verifying the change worked.

Once you get external RDP to the Win10 system set on your custom port, then you can put in a second redirect rule for the default port, aimed at your 2012 Server.

Comment: I swapped redirect on 12345 from ip 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.1 (win10 to sever 2012) and it worked like a charm; 
then roll back to 192.168.1.2 - I cant connect; 
router is passing everything fine

Comment: You're getting warmer - the router isn't redirecting 12345 to 192.168.1.2.  The problem to solve is "why".  try removing the redirect rule for 12345 to 1.1, restart the router, then institute the rule to redirect that port to 1.2.  Also, make sure that your 12345 rule has a unique name, two rules named "RDP" may not work well in the router.

Comment: you did not understand me
1. I set redirect 12345 to 192.168.1.2:3389 - does not work
2. I change redirect 12345 to 192.168.1.1:3389 - it works
3. I roll back redirect 12345 to 192.168.1.2:3389 - does not work
and of course I tried
leaving only Win10 on 3389
changing default port to different 
nothing helps

Comment: How so? You've a specific IP address that the router will not institute a redirected port.  Did you swap addresses between server and desktop with the existing verified rules as outlined in my answer?  That's how you rule out if it's IP, or if it's OS.

Comment: Yep. I left only Win10 on defualt port and one rule (default 3389 -> 3389)
Win10 just does not accept rdp from internet while it works fine (every port i used) on lan

Comment: That means that the OS settings are good.  It has to be on the router.  If you have Wireshark (download it - it's free), install on all three systems, and watch for connections on 3389 and 12345 on your laptop, your win10 system, and your 2012 server.  That should reveal where the traffic is going, and where it is getting blocked.

Comment: All right. 
I didnt try to watch traffic on such low level. 
Will do.

Comment: Also... check the system, security, and app logs on the 2012 server (where it works) and on the desktop system (where it does not).  cross-check timestamps to your LAN and your WAN attempts.  You'll find it, I have faith. :)